# "on click" to replace hover for navigation on ipad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad

I have been working a webpage that has a drop down menu when the user hovers over the tabs. However this fails to work on ipads.

I have tried using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
jQuery('.floor-menus').attr("onclick","return true");
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<ul class="floor-menus">
```

Which works fantastic but then the user can not click off the dropdown menu to make it disappear again.

Does anybody know how I can add this feature to my code? I am a beginner so if anyone can point me in the right direction I will be extremely thankful :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `jQuery('.floor-menus').attr("onclick","return true");` you could use jQuery `toggleClass` (http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to add/remove a CSS class that is hiding or showing the menu.